# Python: compressing csv files to .gz throws error

Tags: python

i am trying to compress csv files in a directory using gzip module, it is giving an error (AttributeError & TypeError) as shown below. Not sure what went wrong. Please help.

First Function: lists the files with a match..

`sample files in archive directory:`

```
cherry_20200719.csv
cherry_20200972.csv
cherry_20830833.csv
```

content of each sample file have multiple row.. something like below.

```
cherry,model8,9893,0380
cherry,model9,9894,0390
cherry,model10,9895,0410
```

Python3 Code: to list the files and then compress them.

```
import gzip, csv
def List_files(filepath, substr):
    X = []
    Y = []
    for path, subdirs, files in sorted(os.walk(filepath), reverse=True):
        for name in files:
            X.append(os.path.join(path, name))
    Y = [line for line in X if 'backup' not in line]
    if substr == 'apple':
        return [str for str in Y if any(sub in str for sub in substr) and 'xml' in str]
    elif substr == 'cherry':
        return [str for str in Y if substr in str]
    else:
        return ""

for file in List_files('archive/', 'cherry'):
    Y = open(file).readlines()
    with gzip.open(file + '.gz', 'a') as zip:
        zip.write(Y)
        zip.close()
```

I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Maria\test.py", line 52, in <module>
    zip.write(Y)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 260, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

If i change `zip.write(Y)` to `zip.write(Y.encode())`, getting below error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Maria\test.py", line 52, in <module>
    zip.write(Y.encode())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Not Sure, what mistake i did.. Please help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
for file in List_files('archive/', 'cherry'):
    Y = open(file, 'rb' ).read()
    with gzip.open(file + '.gz', 'a') as zip:
        zip.write(Y)
        zip.close()
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for response.. i am getting "ValueError: Must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode and at most one plus" error. @ Y = open(file, 'b').read()

Answer (score 2):

`open(file).readlines()` will return a list containing every individual line as a string.

Try `open(file, "rb").read()` which will open the file and read all of it in raw binary. But you should close the file afterwards, so

```
with open(file, "rb") as f:
  Y = f.read()
```

might be better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.. i am getting TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"  error with this modification.